# How can I get contents of page with page structure?

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm currently looking kernel source code about page cache.

I got a `struct page (include/linux/mm_type.h)`, and I want to read and save the real contents of that page descriptor points to.

I found `address_space_operations` and It seems could help me, but I don't know how they work and how to use. Also, `aops->readpage` get `structure file` as argument which I don't have.

What I want to do is just print the contents of page cache (with printk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but perhaps safer approach is using `kmap()` from `linux/highmem.h` which will return associated virtual address if the page is already mapped, or else will create a mapping for the given page and return the address for the same that you can dereference from your module.

Comment: Thank you. You help me a lot. The key function to access page data from page struct is kmap().

Comment: Glad to know. In case you are exploring for the sake of personal study I would like to recommend this course material: https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~cruse/cs635s03/